# PL/SQL Group By Sequence

Tags: plsql, group-by, sequence

I have a table like this:

[image: Table 1]

I want to group by this 3 columns (col1, col2, col3) with a specific sequence, to get something like this:

[image]

Is there any kind of function to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytical function Dense_Rank() would work well here.

```
SELECT col1 , col2 , col3 
     , DENSE_Rank() OVER (ORDER BY COL1, COL2, COL3) AS MYGROUP 
FROM REFTABLE
```

Rank() vs Dense_rank() dense rank will keep numbers sequential w/o gap whereas rank will introduce gaps.  In your example 3, B, Y twice may be assigned rank 3 but the next value would be assigned rank 5 if rank was used 4 if dense_rank() is used.

Link to [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

Note each time the query runs the Dense_rank is assigned so #'s can change as data changes.  If you want the numbers to be unique then you would need to store them. and then force Dense_Rank to start at a seed being the highest # in the stored results.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work. I need to get the number of my group in a column.
In other words, i need a new number everytime the col1, col2 and col3 changes.

Comment: Oh!!! I missed the 680 duplicate.  `Dense_Rank()` or `Rank()`instead of `row_number()`. with a partition by your col1, col2, col3

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174 provides a list of analytic functions which you may find useful on your SQL journey.

Comment: I tried this, but still doesnt work:

`WITH REFTABLE AS(
  SELECT 'A' AS COL1,'X' AS COL2, 'Z' AS COL3 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS COL1,'X' AS COL2, 'Z' AS COL3 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS COL1,'Y' AS COL2, 'Z' AS COL3 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS COL1,'Y' AS COL2, 'W' AS COL3 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' AS COL1,'Y' AS COL2, 'W' AS COL3 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT col1
     , col2
     , col3
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY COL1, COL2, COL3 ORDER BY COL1, COL2, COL3) AS MYGROUP
FROM REFTABLE;`

Comment: bah I messed up no partition needed.  added image and results above.  it's what caused the numbers to restart for each group.

Answer (score 0):

add rownum will add sequence number per row:

```
select col1, col2, col3, rownum as mygroup from table a;
```